# How to measure confidence in classifier of non-independent data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, confidence-interval

I have some noisy high dimensional data, and each data point has a "score". The scores are roughly normally distributed. Some scores are known and some are unknown; I want to separate the unknown points into two groups, based on whether I think the score is positive or not.

I have a black box which, given some data points and their scores, gives me a hyperplane correctly separating the points (if one exists).

I separate the points with known score into two disjoint sets for training and validation respectively.

Then, repeatedly (say *k* times), I do the following:

- Randomly select some data points with positive score and some points with negative score from the training set (for some fixed positive values for *m* and *n*).
- Use the black box to (try to) get a separating hyperplane for these sampled points.
- If I get a hyperplane back, save it.

Now I have some hyperplanes (say I have 0 < *k'* <= *k* of them).

I use these hyperplanes to separate the validation set. I select the hyperplane which correctly classifies the most points as having positive or negative score (number of correct positives + number of correct negatives).

My question is: **How can I measure the statistical confidence that the finally selected hyperplane is better than random?**

Here's what I've done so far:

Say there are *n* points in the validation set. If a hyperplane correctly classifies a point with probability *p*, and this is independent for all the points, we can use a binomial distribution.

Let F be the cdf of the binomial distribution. Let X be the number of correctly classified points in the validation set (so we are assuming *X ~ B(n, p)*). Then *P(X <= x) = F(x)*.

Now, we have *k'* hyperplanes. Let's assume these can be represented as *k'* IID variables *X1, X2, ..., Xk'*.

Now *P(max(X1, X1, ..., Xk') <= x) = F(x) ^ k'*.

Let's say a random hyperplane is one as above where *p* equals the proportion of positive scores in the total (so if it's three quarters positive, *p = 0.75*).

Sticking some numbers in, I ran these numbers. Let *p = 0.5* for simplicity. Suppose I want to check if the selected hyperplane is better than random with probability > 0.95.

If *n = 2000*, I need to classify 1080 correctly to have confidence greater than 0.95 that this classifier is better than random (I think, unless I did the calculation wrong).

**However**, if the points themselves are not independent, this doesn't work. Suppose many of the points are identical so the effective size of the set is much smaller than *n*. If *n = 20*, you need to get 18 correct for 0.95 confidence; extrapolating that suggests you'd need 1800/2000.

**I am sure that the points are not independent, but I'm not sure in what way, or how to go about measuring that and accounting for it in a calculation similar to the above.**

I've been reading this paper: [The binomial distribution with dependent Bernoulli trials by PAG Van der Geest](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0094965042000193224). It describes an algorithm for estimating a binomial distribution for dependent bernoulli trials given marginal expectations for each event and "second order correlations" between (some) pairs of events. I think I could probably figure out how to estimate these (e.g. based on a distance metric between the points in the space), but I don't understand the details of the paper well enough to easily implement the described algorithm.

Comment: Could you say more specifically what you mean by "the finally selected hyperplane is better than random"? It sounds like you want to calculate a p value, but it's not clear to me what the null hypothesis is

Comment: If all you want to test is whether the hyperplane is better than random, then how you got it doesn't seem to matter. But it may be worth stating what "better than random means", e.g. better than a predictor that just guesses based on the relative counts of the positive vs negative. Incidentally, when you say the scores are normally distributed, are you saying that the marginal distribution of the scores is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Comment: It seems to me like it may indeed matter a great deal how the random hyperplane would be chosen, i.e., what the null hypothesis is. "A" random hyperplane could be far away from the actual samples, just like "a" random point in the plane from a scatterplot.

Comment: I've thought about the problem a bit more and edited with much more details

Comment: The marginal distribution of the scores is not N(0, 1), it's normal with some other mean and variance

Comment: How do you get 1080 for n=2000?

Comment: Do you at least know which points are dependent? IF so, you could account for it using permutation test and shuffling within dependence groups.

Comment: @rep_ho they might all be dependent

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as @Stephan Kolassa mention is what "random" means in "better than random". It could mean

a) a random classifier, one that selects positive or negative for a new data at random.

b) a random hyperplane in the space

c) a random hyperplane among the ones selected by the procedure of you describe above (in the bullet points).

a)

If it is a random classifier, than the best random classifier is the one that guesses "+" with probability p+ which is the proportion of the "+" in the training set. Then a random classifier will be right with probability p+^2 + p-^2 (where p- = 1-p+)

The you use a binomial test to check if the number of times your classifier is correct has p-value < 0.05.

It does not matter that the data is not independent - it clearly it is not if you think that there is a classifier that may work on it - the random classifier  treats the data as independent - each prediction is totally independent than the others.

b) and c)

If the "random" in your sentence is a random hyperplane, or a random hyperplane selected by the procedure, I think the solution is the same: Monte Carlo. Generate a large random sample of the hyperplanes, and verify how the accuracy (number of correct predictions) of your best selected hyperplane compares with the distribution of accuracies of the random hyperplanes.

I think there is some issues on how to generate random hyperplanes in space in case of b) but I am not competent to discuss it. In case of c) just collect your hyperplanes.

But there is a general problem. Your best hyperplane is selected as the one with higher accuracy among the constructed hyperplanes in the validation set - by definition this hyperplane will have higher accuracy than all other ones, and if you have more than 20 constructed hyperplanes, you can have certainty below p=0.05 that this is the better than a random one!

I *think* you have to perform this Monte Carlo test on a different validation set - not the one you use to select the hyperplane with higher accuracy!!